# Conjunction issue in OPENIE 6

Tags: stanford-nlp, transformer-model, allennlp, triples, knowledge-graph

I am using OPENIE6 (https://github.com/dair-iitd/openie6) with the following input:-

**President Trump met the leaders of India and China.**

But I am getting only one triplet:-

```
ARG1 = President trump
V = met
ARG2 = the leaders of India and China.
```

Instead, as mentioned in the documentation and demos, there should be two triplets:-

```
ARG1 = President trump
V = met,
ARG2 = the leaders of India.

ARG1 = President trump
V = met
ARG2 = the leaders of China.
```

Can anyone help, what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before the full stop. The coordinate boundary model can split more accurately after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).